# I get lots of hand cramps from both mouse and keyboard use, how can I minimize that?

Tags: work-environment, software-industry

I am a programmer and sometimes I get Repetitive Stress from using the keyboard and mouse a lot.
I find that my hand gets 'crampy' after a while and I have to keep switching hands for the mouse.

Is there anything else I can do to minimize this?

Comment: Hi Michael - your question was closed for the moment because it is an extremely broad question (searching "repetitive stress" or "repetitive strain" at Amazon produces numerous results).  If you would like to discuss ways to edit the question so that it is well-scoped such that it could fit in the SE Q&A style, please ask in [meta] or [chat].  Thanks!

Comment: Good points.  Let me give it a go.

Comment: Michael, actually I voted to close as off topic, I see this as a medical issue not a workplace one. RSI is a catch all term, and there's no one size fits all solution. I've seen colleagues thinking the same as you, that the problem was their chair, keyboard, desk, whatever, when in fact it was something completely unrelated, and in one case following advice from the internet made it (a lot) worse. I really think you should visit at least a GP, if not a specialist.

Comment: No problem.  Just seemed like something I had experienced that many other folks, especially fellow programmers experience too so I thought there might be some sage and wise opinions.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/06/programming-your-hands.html

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suggest the Kinesis Freestyle. Texter 0.6, autohotkey, etc do help.

Take time off from keyboarding. A week is doable, yeah?